# How to Capture the result of the dynamic query and store into another table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have table.

| QueryID | Query |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | select count(*) from emp name is not null |
| 2 | select count(*) from dept where id is not null |

Now I am writing a stored procedure to run the query and store the results in target table as shown here:

| QueryID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2300 |
| 2 | 4500 |

But I am getting the result as below table by using this stored procedure:

| QueryID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecuteQueriesAndStoreResults
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @queryID NVARCHAR(255);

    -- Declare variables for query results
    DECLARE @queryResult NVARCHAR(255);

    -- Declare a cursor to loop through TableA
    DECLARE @curQuery CURSOR;

    SET @curQuery = CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT Query, QueryID 
       FROM TableA;

    OPEN @curQuery;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @curQuery INTO @query, @queryID;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Execute the dynamic query
        EXEC(@query);

        -- Capture the result of the dynamic query
        SET @queryResult = @@ROWCOUNT; -- Store the result as needed
       
        -- Insert the result along with the QueryID into ResultsTable
        INSERT INTO ResultsTable (QueryID, Result)
        VALUES (@queryID, @queryResult);

        FETCH NEXT FROM @curQuery INTO @query, @queryID;
    END;

    CLOSE @curQuery;
    DEALLOCATE @curQuery;
END;
```

| QueryID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2300 |
| 2 | 4500 |

Comment: The query says `SELECT COUNT(*)` so `@@ROWCOUNT` will be `1`, not the result of the count. Is the query pattern _always_ `select {one value in one row} from ...`?

Comment: Storing queries in a table to execute them at various times sounds like a design that went the wrong way.

Comment: `@query NVARCHAR(255)` <-- I'd be careful here. Why limit it to 255? (Also why isn't `@QueryID` an `int`?)

Comment: Are all queries a simple `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `1` for every query because:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.all_columns;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; -- always 1!
```

Assuming the query pattern is *always*...

> `SELECT {something like a count} and only one row`

...you can do this:

```
-- somewhere way above:

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

-- then inside the cursor:

SET @sql = N'WITH cte(rcount) AS ('
  + @query + ') SELECT @QueryID, rcount FROM cte;';

INSERT dbo.ResultsTable(QueryID, Result)
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@QueryID int', @QueryID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec` to execute dynamic SQL. It allows for parameters to be passed back and forth.

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max);
declare @params nvarchar(max);
declare @rowcount int;
set @stmt = N'select @rowcount = count(*) from dbo.YOURTABLE where ID is not null;'
set @params = N'@rowcount int output';
exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
   , @params = @params
   , @rowcount = @rowcount output;
select @rowcount;
```